# How can Install plugin django CMS

Tags: plugins, installation, django-cms

I'm using win7 64, Installed Django CMS and mysql.
I created new site and login into admin page OK. Create home page ok.

Next: How can i install a plugin?
For example, i want a blog or news to post.

Thank you for your help.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The standard way to install a Django plugin is through [pip package manager](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pip). You should already have it installed.
Then, just run:

```
pip install "plugin name"
```

For example:

```
pip install aldryn-blog
```

This command will install *aldryn-blog* and all its dependencies.
For this particular plugin, there are many dependencies involved, so if you want to use it in your Django-cms app, you have to include them all in your main *settings.py* file, under *INSTALLED_APPS*, like this:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    …

    'aldryn_blog',
    'aldryn_common',
    'django_select2',
    'djangocms_text_ckeditor',
    'easy_thumbnails',
    'filer',
    'taggit',
    # for search
    'aldryn_search',
    'haystack',
    …
)
```

Please look [here](https://github.com/aldryn/aldryn-blog) for details on this particular plugin.